# Get value of string in try other method

Tags: java, mysql, swing, actionlistener

So, this prog getting value `car_number` from data base `"getReprt" method` , and give name to button as value from db. Also, I need to get this value next, to action listener `btn_listener` for each button it s own value. But whis this code, I only get last data value, and it`s the same for each button. How can I give every actionlistener situation differnet values?
what am I doing wrong?

```java
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JSplitPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;

public class Car2q {
    private Connection con;
    private ResultSet rs;
    static JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea();
    static login frame = new login();
    static JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
    static JSplitPane splitPane = new JSplitPane();
    static JPanel panel_left = new JPanel();
    static JPanel panel_right = new JPanel();

    static class login extends JFrame {

        public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
            final Car2q c2q = new Car2q();
            c2q.getReport();

            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.pack();
            frame.setVisible(true);
            frame.setSize(550, 300);
            frame.setVisible(true);
            frame.add(splitPane);
            splitPane.setSize(550, 300);
            splitPane.setLeftComponent(scrollPane);
            splitPane.setLeftComponent(panel_left);
            splitPane.setRightComponent(panel_right);
            panel_left.setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 1, 5, 5));
            panel_right.setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 2, 5, 5));
        }
    }

    public Car2q() {
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
            con = DriverManager.getConnection("");
            con.createStatement();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error: " + e);
        }
    }

    public String getReport() {
        String car_number = null;
        String report = null;
        List car_number_list = new ArrayList<>();
        try {
            PreparedStatement st = null;
            String query2 = "select * FROM car_register";
            st = con.prepareStatement(query2);
            rs = st.executeQuery();
            while (rs.next()) {
                car_number = rs.getString("car_number");
                String gotit = rs.getString("car_number");
                JButton btn = new JButton(gotit);
                btn.setSize(100, 100);
                panel_left.add(btn);
                ActionListener actionListener = new btn_listener();
                btn.addActionListener(actionListener);
            }
        }
        catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return car_number;
    }

    public class btn_listener implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            Car2q c2q = new Car2q();
            String car = c2q.getReport();
            System.out.println(car);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Pass the value to the btn_listener constructor and store it in a field of that class.

Comment: Java naming conventions have class names start with an upper case letter and use CamelCase with no underscores. Example: BtnListener.

Comment: @tgdavies I am rly new in Java, can you be more specific?) you meen something like that `public class btn_listener implements ActionListener {
     public btn_listener(){
      try {
       public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        Car2q c2q = new Car2q();
     String car = c2q.getReport();


       System.out.println(car);
        
       }
      }
     }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write your button listener like this:

```
    public class btn_listener implements ActionListener {
        private final String car_number;

        public bin_listener(String car_number) {
            this.car_number = car_number;
        }
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            System.out.println(car_number);
        }
    }
```

Then in your loop you create the ActionListener:

```
    ActionListener actionListener = new btn_listener(car_number);
```

And of course to be idiomatic Java you should use `carNumber` and `BtnListener` and so on.

Answer (score 0):

```
car_number = rs.getString("car_number");
String gotit = rs.getString("car_number");
JButton btn = new JButton(gotit);
```

You don't need two variables that contain the same value. You just need to set the car number as the text of the button.

Then the code in your `ActionListener` becomes:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{
    JButton button = (JButton)e.getSource();
    System.out.println( button.getText() );
}
```

The `ActionListener` is now generic and can be shared by all your buttons.

So your code becomes:

```
        ActionListener buttonListener = new CarButtonListener();

        while (rs.next()) {
            //car_number = rs.getString("car_number");
            String gotit = rs.getString("car_number");
            JButton btn = new JButton(gotit);
            btn.setSize(100, 100);
            panel_left.add(btn);
            //ActionListener actionListener = new btn_listener();
            //btn.addActionListener(actionListener);
            btn.addActionListener(buttonListener);
        }
```

This allows your code to be more efficient and use less memory since you only need a single instance of the listener.

Note I renamed your "btn_listener" class to "CarButtonListener" since:

1. class names should be descriptive
2. each word in the class name should start with an upper case character